# Unit test a possible infinite loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I have a certain function that does this:

```
function someFunction(...){
  ...
  var remaining = somePositiveValue
  while(--remaining){/*ajax stuff*/}
  ...
  return deferredObject;
}
```

Basically it gets initial data loaded earlier in the code. `somePositiveValue` is taken from that data and is fed to this function. As seen above, that value controls the loop. Now suppose `somePositiveValue` was returned as `0` due to some unforseen bug on the server's part. The code will break and loop infinitely. It's easy to append `> 0` though.

But before that, how do I test if a function goes to an infinite loop? How do I fail that on the unit test? I use QUnit by the way. Is unit testing the right way for this or is there another way?

Comment: You don't -- at least not without running the function.  That is the very definition of the Halting Problem.

Comment: @roe: And how would a machine know it had entered an infinite loop?

Comment: @cHao; I don't know, but you said "at least not without running the function", so I figured you knew. ;)

Comment: @roe: In JavaScript?  Not really.  Once the value got past -(2^53) or so, `--remaining` would not be enough to move `remaining` to the next representable value.  So it very well could run forever.

Comment: I meant "without running the function and potentially having it run forever".  :)

Comment: @cHao; Interesting. I did not know that, I figured javascript had integer overflow like most other. Cool! :)

Comment: More related to your code, how about not using a loop? If you're doing AJAX stuff you can probably sequence promises dynamically.

Comment: @elclanrs The loop creates "promises" and stores them in an array. Then I use `.when()` to check if they're done (hence the `return deferredObject` at the end).

Comment: I see... I guess you could solve it like `range(0,remaining).map(function(i){ return promise })` so if `remaining` is zero, then the array is empty. I'd say the best way to test for an infinite loop is to try to get rid of the possiblity of an infinite loop.

Comment: You cannot, but maybe you can use a Web Worker that refreshes every time.

Answer (score 1):

If *remaining* might be zero to start with, post decrement it:

```
while (remaining--)
```

If *remaining* might be -ve to start with do a comparison instead of implicit boolean:

```
while (--remaining > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing a code that might turn into an infinite loop, you can always force QUnit to stop waiting after a while.
For instance add this line at the end of your test :

```
asyncTest( "Test that might infinitly loop ", function( assert ) {
    // Your test
    // ...

    // Force stop after 2 secondes
    setTimeout(start, 2000); // QUnit < 2.x
});
```